# match two file and print differences

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, compare, findstr

I use this command "findstr /livg:" for merge two file in a new one in both direction, but command FAIL if a second file is empty, how can I solve this problem?

```
file a.txt:

1st_file_1st_row
2nd_file_2st_row
1st_file_3st_row
1st_file_4st_row
1st_file_4st_row
1st_file_5st_row
```

.....

```
file b.txt

1st_file_1st_row
1st_file_2st_row
1st_file_3st_row
1st_file_4st_row
2st_file_4st_row
1st_file_5st_row
```

first run

```
findstr /livg:a.txt b.txt

1st_file_2st_row
2st_file_4st_row
```

second run

```
findstr /livg:b.txt a.txt

2nd_file_2st_row
```

if b.txt (second file) is empty I got no row in output, but a.txt is full and I need all row!

thank you in advance

Comment: check https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html and https://ss64.com/nt/comp.html

Comment: Problem could be solved like this trick:

    findstr /livg:a.txt b.txt || type a.txt